# Automatically set axis limits making them surpass all the drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

The main idea behind this post is getting adapted tikzpicture xy axis. I mean, axis that surpass all the points drew (or pretended to be drew).

In my initial tikzpicture, the limit of the drawings is determined by the axis' lenghts. And I solved that using `clip = false`. I found that in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343219/pgfplots-objects-outside-axis-are-clipped) post. It seems that `clip = false` is something essential.

[image]

Even so, axis doesn't reach the limit of the drawings. I was looking for a shorter x+ axis (closer to the drawings right limit, 6), longer y+ axis (surpassing the top of the triangle a little bit: drawings upper limit), longer x- axis (surpassing circumference) and shorter y- axis (same reason than x+ axis).

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450756/pgfplots-modify-axis-after-end-axis-cut-tikzpicture-after-drawing) post, I've read in the comments that "you do not have to set an `ymax` value. If you do not set it, pgfplots will make sure that all data points are shown". Also, in that comments it is said that using `\addplot` will solve the axis problem. I decided to do a few verifications: adding a drawing using `\addplot` and erasing `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax`. This is the result:

[image]

Image 3 is simply a disaster. Image 4 doesn't have any difference with Image 2, `\addplot` didn't solve the axis-adapt problem.

In my opinion, `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` are the problem here. I'd like to draw multiple pictures based on parameters (which I've learned recently: [own post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559438/tikzpictures-inside-newcommand-text-below-tikzpicture-space-between-side-by-si)) so modifying `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` is not viable. Keeping that in mind, I gave another try:

[image]

Image 5 is so compressed. I thought it was due to `axis equal` because `ymax` is way higher than `|xmin|, xmax`, but, as you can see in Image 6, I was wrong.

Finally, I found this post: [Set vertical axis limits above/beneath the maximum/minimum resp. value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294398/set-vertical-axis-limits-above-beneath-the-maximum-minimum-resp-value). It seemed to be exactly what I wanted, so I used `enlarge x limits=0.3` (and y). But using it without `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` returned me Image 3 again. And using it with `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` is not an option, because tikzpictures in newcommand will have variable values.

So now, my question is: how do I manage to get my y+ axis above the 'ymax drawings' value' and the y- axis below the 'ymin drawings' value'? And the same idea on x axis.

My MWE (Original Image) is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmargins{2.5cm}      
{1.5cm}                
{15.5cm}               
{23.42cm}           
{10pt}                 
{1cm}                 
{0pt}                    
{2cm}

\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\example}[3]{
    \tikzmath{
        \mya = #1;
        \myb = #2;
        \myr = #3;
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%   clip = false,
    axis lines* = middle,
    axis equal,
    xmin = -5, xmax= 8, ymin= -5, ymax = 7,
    xtick = \empty, ytick = \empty,
    extra x ticks={\mya, 2,6},
    extra y ticks={\myb, -1}
    ]
%   \addplot[domain=-4:5, color=cyan]{x^2-2*x-1};
    \filldraw [red] (axis cs:\mya,\myb) circle (0.1);
    \filldraw [red] (axis cs:0,-1) circle (0.1);
    \draw[dashed, red] (\mya, \myb) -- (0, -1);
    \draw[purple] (-3,-3) -- (2,2);
    \filldraw [dashed, green, fill opacity=0.1] (axis cs:\mya,\myb) circle(\myr);
    \filldraw [blue, fill opacity=0.2](2,0) -- (6,0) -- (4,10) -- (2,0);
    \node [label={(a,b)}] at (\mya, \myb) {};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\example{-7}{4}{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `\addplot` *does* solve your problem, but you need to draw all the elements in your diagram with it, not just plot some random parabola.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmargins{2.5cm}      
{1.5cm}                
{15.5cm}               
{23.42cm}           
{10pt}                 
{1cm}                 
{0pt}                    
{2cm}

\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\example}[3]{
    \tikzmath{
        \mya = #1;
        \myb = #2;
        \myr = #3;
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines* = middle,
    axis equal,
    xtick={\mya, 2,6},
    ytick={\myb, -1}
    ]

    \addplot[red,mark=*,dashed, mark options={solid}] coordinates {(\mya,\myb)(0,-1)};
    \addplot[purple] coordinates{(-3,-3)(2,2)};
    \addplot[dashed, draw,fill,fill opacity=0.1,green,domain=0:360] ({\mya+cos(x)*\myr},{\myb+sin(x)*\myr});
    \addplot[blue, fill, fill opacity=0.2] coordinates {(2,0)(6,0)(4,10)(2,0)};
    \node [above] at (\mya, \myb) {(a,b)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\example{-7}{4}{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think the title of this post fits with the problem I had? @Torbjørn T.

Comment: @Iborra Yes, I think so. If you wanted to make a bit more specific, you could perhaps add the word "Automatically" at the start, to emphasize that just adjusting `xmin` etc. manually isn't good enough.